# How to write an umlaut in bibtex style file?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I want to customize a BibTeX style file (`.bst`), where there is the following function for unpublished works:

```
FUNCTION {format.howpublished.address.year}
{ howpublished empty$
    { address empty$
        { "No address in " cite$ warning$ }
        { " \apyformat {" oaddress.opublisher.oyear.format address "}" * }
       if$
    }
    { address empty$
        { "There's only a howpublished (no address) in " cite$ * warning$ " \apyformat {" oaddress.opublisher.oyear.format howpublished * "}" * }
        { " \apyformat {" oaddress.opublisher.oyear.format address * "\bpubaddr {} " * howpublished "}" * * }
       if$
    }
    if$
}
```

I want to change the string "No address in" to another string using the german umlauts ('ö', 'ä' and 'ü'). But simply typing an umlaut results in compilation errors. How to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you can't easily use `"` in a string in a `.bst` file. One way is to use the function `int.to.chr$`. Easiest would be to define a command `\myumlaut` in the bibliography preamble.

Your original function `begin.bib` might look like this:

```
FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ preamble$ empty$
    'skip$
    { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
  if$
  "\providecommand{\bysame}{\leavevmode\hbox to3em{\hrulefill}\thinspace}"
    write$ newline$
  "\begin{thebibliography}{"  longest.label  * "}" *
    write$ newline$
}
```

and you modify it to this:

```
FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ preamble$ empty$
    'skip$
    { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
  if$
  "\let\myumlaut\" #34 int.to.chr$ *
    write$ newline$
  "\providecommand{\bysame}{\leavevmode\hbox to3em{\hrulefill}\thinspace}"
    write$ newline$
  "\begin{thebibliography}{"  longest.label  * "}" *
    write$ newline$
}
```

Now, you can write `schöne` as `sch\myumlaut{o}ne`.